# Регулярные выражения для сортировки ссылок Python

Tags: python, re

Час добрый
Подскажите пожалуйста какими регулярными выражениями можно собирать ссылки следующих видов:

```
1)Телеграм https://t.me/
2)Инстаграм https://instagram.com/
3)ВК https://vk.ru/
4)Facebook https://facebook.com/
5)Если ни в одно условие не попало, но все таки есть https://, то сохранить в отдельную переменную
```

Только начинаю разбираться с регулярными выражениями, буду благодарен если поможете.
P.s. Ссылки в примерах обрезаны, скажем, за место https://instagram.com/ будет ссылка на какую-то страницу в инстаграме, на месте телеграма, ссылка на тг канал и дальше по аналогии с остальными примерами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то регулярки здесь вовсе не нужны :) Можно использовать оператор принадлежности in. Но если нужно именно через регулярки, то вам поможет этот код:

```
import re

url = ваша ссылка
telegram, instagram, vk, facebook, other = list(), list(), list(), list(), list()
if re.match("https://t.me/", url):
    telegram.append(url)
elif re.match("https://instagram.com/", url):
    instagram.append(url)
elif re.match("https://vk.ru/", url):
    vk.append(url)
elif re.match("https://facebook.com/", url):
    facebook.append(url)
elif re.match("https://", url):
    other.append(url)
```